# Having trouble getting custom shears to work on blocks in new 1.14.4 forge of minecraft

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to add custom shears to my mod. I made the class and extended it to original ShearsItem class. They only seem to work on sheep. When I try to break leaves/cobweb nothing drops. I tried looking at other mods that add shears and couldn't find anything speacial that they have added. I'm new to coding so I might have overlooked something.

```
import net.minecraft.item.*;

public class wooden_shears extends ShearsItem {

    public wooden_shears() {
        super(new Item.Properties()
                .maxStackSize(1)
                .defaultMaxDamage(16)
                .group(ItemGroup.TOOLS));
        setRegistryName("wooden_shears");
    }
}
```

Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will hava a much higher chance to get an answer if you post this on the forge forums.

Here are some threads you might want to hava a look at:
https://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/topic/71894-terrible-kludge1142-making-custom-shears-work-on-leaves/

https://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/topic/77244-1144-how-to-implement-custom-shears/
It seems you're out of luck for now.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the answer. I was digging in forge forums right now as well and this is what I found.  

Tldr: The way minecraft implemented their loottables, they can't understand inheritence. For modded shears to drop items you will have to replace all vanilla recipes for all the leaf blocks. If some other mod tries to override you, it'll break your mod.

https://github.com/MinecraftForge/MinecraftForge/pull/5871/#issuecomment-542697064